# Optimization of a vectorized count function

Tags: r, optimization

My question is one about R code optimization for a specific task. Let's say I have a vector of length `size` containing integers between `1` and `x`. I want to create a function that will output a vector of the same length counting the occurence of each element of the vector. There is plenty of ways to do that, but I want to do it the fastest as I can with large value of `size`.

Let's do a quick example. I want a function `f()` that will give the following:

```
f(5, 6)
##  $input
##  [1] 3 5 2 5 4 5
##  
##  $output
##  [1] 1 3 1 3 1 3
```

A first naive function to do so would be

```
f1 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = sapply(input, function(i){sum(input==i)})
  )
}

set.seed(20190920)
f1(5, 6)
##  $input
##  [1] 3 5 2 5 4 5
##  
##  $output
##  [1] 1 3 1 3 1 3
```

Here is another approach which is faster for large values of `size`

```
f2 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  temp <- sapply(unique(input), function(i){setNames(sum(input==i), i)})
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = setNames(sapply(input, function(i){temp[as.character(i)]}), NULL)
  )
}

set.seed(20190920)
f2(5, 6)
##  $input
##  [1] 3 5 2 5 4 5
##  
##  $output
##  [1] 1 3 1 3 1 3
```

I did some bechmarking with different values of `size` to see the improvement of the median processing time of `f2` over the one of `f1`. Here is the code for reference and the processed plot below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

sizes <- seq(0, 20000, 1000)
median_f1 <- sapply(sizes, function(size){
  median(microbenchmark(f1(10, size))$time)
})
median_f2 <- sapply(sizes, function(size){
  median(microbenchmark(f2(10, size))$time)
})

data.table(sizes, median_f1, median_f2) %>%
  melt(c("sizes")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=sizes, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=sizes, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

I expanded the range of `sizes` just to confirm the (already apparent) trend:
[image]

It is easy to see that `f2()` is way much faster than `f1()` but still, for my needs, it's too slow. I have to do the following over multi-dimensional arrays with the size parameter sometimes larger than 1M. I am looking for someone who could help me create an `f3()` function that would be significantly faster than `f2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My variant uses the function `table()`, it is the function `f3()` below:

```
library("microbenchmark")

f1 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = sapply(input, function(i){sum(input==i)})
  )
}

f2 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  temp <- sapply(unique(input), function(i){setNames(sum(input==i), i)})
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = setNames(sapply(input, function(i){temp[as.character(i)]}), NULL)
  )
}

f3 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = table(factor(input, levels=1:x))[input]
  )
}

microbenchmark(f1(5, 10000), f2(5, 10000), f3(5, 10000), unit="relative")
# > microbenchmark(f1(5, 10000), f2(5, 10000), f3(5, 10000), unit="relative")
# Unit: relative
#         expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq        max neval cld
# f1(5, 10000) 241.73176 227.69538 230.40873 225.5085 225.12230 109.425800   100   c
# f2(5, 10000)  13.36599  12.53868  12.10007  12.4553  12.48617   4.405781   100  b 
# f3(5, 10000)   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.0000   1.00000   1.000000   100 a
```

Here is also a function `f4()` which uses `tabulate()`:

```
f4 <- function(x, size){
  input <- sample(x, size, TRUE)
  list(
    input  = input,
    output = tabulate(input, nbins=x)[input]
  )
}

microbenchmark(f1(5, 10000), f2(5, 10000), f3(5, 10000), f4(5, 10000), unit="relative")
# > microbenchmark(f1(5, 10000), f2(5, 10000), f3(5, 10000), f4(5, 10000), unit="relative")
# Unit: relative
#         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
# f1(5, 10000) 455.819135 453.731740 484.839866 447.794049 496.980368 627.25732   100   c
# f2(5, 10000)  25.100383  24.890488  24.927370  24.409499  24.577944  27.29102   100  b 
# f3(5, 10000)   1.889913   1.914113   1.984959   1.950015   1.955407   5.10581   100 a  
# f4(5, 10000)   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.00000   100 a
```